# Filter articles in blog category by article id in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla3.0

In category.php model, there is a bunch of $model->setState filters, that shapes the output of articles.

I am trying to add new setState, that will filter output of articles by given id's

```
$model->setState('filter.id', $params->get('id_articles', array());
```

but still wont filter. So i tried with direct id input:

```
$model->setState('filter.id', '280');
```

and still, the output is not filtered at all.

To  be sure if this kind of filter works, i modified the model->setState for featured articles:

```
$model->setState('filter.featured', 'only');
```

and this proves that $model->setState works properly, but it won't accept filtering by article id.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `$itemid = JRequest::getInt('id', 0) . ':' . JRequest::getInt('Itemid', 0); $model->setState('filter.id', $itemid);`

Comment: The problem is, that even with specific number as :
$model->setState('filter.id', '280');
does not activate this filter, it passes trough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your populateState() method set the state to :

```
$articleIds = explode(',', $params->get('id_articles'));
$this->setState('filter.article_id', $articleIds);

$this->setState('filter.article_id', $articleIds);
```

then in your getItems() method just set the state in the model to:

```
$model->setState('filter.article_id', $this->getState('filter.article_id'));
```

and you'll get the desired result.

Comment: Its really strange, because this "article_id" does not appear anywhere else! 
But it works, so i'm accepting this answer!